# Not able to send a view/template through email in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, model-view-controller

i have a codeigniter project through which i wish to send emails to the user.I wish to send the templates having html code effect, however inside the email i am getting html code, instead of view. Can anyone please tell how to do so

Code that i am using is

View

```
<?php echo form_open('home/forgot_pass'); ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?php
            $data = array(
                'type'=>'text', 
                'class' => "form-control",
                'name'=>'email',
                'autocomplete'=>'off', 
                'placeholder'=>'Email' 
                );
            ?>
        <?php echo form_input($data); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?php
            $data = array(
                'type'=>'submit',
                'class'=>'btn btn-success btn-block',
                'name'=>'submit',
                'content'=>'Login'
            );

            echo form_button($data); 
        ?>
    </div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Controller

```
public function forgot_pass()
    {
        $this->user_model->forgot_pass();

    }
```

Model

```
public function forgot_pass()
    {
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $this->db->where('email',$email);
        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        $result = $query->row();

        if($result)
            {
                $password = $result->password;

                $from_email = "xyz@gmail.com"; 

                $this->load->library('email'); 

                $this->email->from($from_email, 'ABC');
                $data = array(
                'password'=> $password
                );

                $this->email->to($email); 
                $this->email->subject('Forgot Password');  

                $body = $this->load->view('users/forgot_password_email',$data,TRUE);
                $this->email->message($body);   
                $this->email->send(); 

            }

    }
```

Can anyone tell how to send template in email through codeigniter

forgot_password_email view

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style="padding: 8px;">

        <span style="color:white;text-align:center;margin-left: 45%;font-size: 20px;font-weight: 600;">LITEHIRES</span>

    </nav>

    <div class="container" style="margin-left: 25%; margin-top: 4%;">
        <p style="font-weight: 600; font-size: 18px;">Hi Samya</p>

            <p> You have recently requested for a password on your litehires account. Please use the following password for your account</p>
            <p style=" margin-left: 25%; color: #3498db; font-size: 16px; "><?php echo $password; ?></p>

            <p>Thanks</p>
            <p style=" margin-top: -10px; ">Litehires Team</p>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a third optional parameter lets you change the behavior of the function so that it returns data as a string rather than sending it to your browser. This can be useful if you want to process the data in some way. If you set the parameter to true (boolean) it will return data. The default behavior is false, which sends it to your browser. Remember to assign it to a variable if you want the data returned:

Change

```
$body = $this->load->view('users/forgot_password_email');
```

To

```
$body = $this->load->view('users/forgot_password_email','',true);
```

MODEL

```
public function forgot_pass()
    {
        $from_email = "xyz@gmail.com"; 
        $to_email = trim($this->input->post('email')); //use trim to removes spaces from both sides 
        $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
        $this->load->library('email',$config); 

        $this->email->from($from_email, 'Your Name'); 
        $this->email->to($to_email);
        $this->email->subject('Email Test'); 
        $data['name'] = 'name here'; //post from from
        $data['password'] = 'password'; //new generated password here
        $body = $this->load->view('users/forgot_password_email',$data,true);
        $this->email->message($body);  
        $this->email->send()

    }
```

For more https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#returning-views-as-data

Comment: it worked but it is displaying the html code and not the page

Comment: if you want to display page after sending mail  add last line on model `$this->load->view('users/forgot_password_email');`

Comment: for proper mail send variables to view then take the view as the string.

Comment: I don't want to display the page after sending mail, i want to send the view in email so that the user can see the template form in their email

Comment: I am sorry but i don't think i understood you

Comment: I have updated my code and post, would appreciate if you could look through it once

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132160/discussion-between-hikmat-sijapati-and-user3732711).

Answer (score 0):

```
$body = $this->load->view('users/forgot_password_email' ,true);
```

this convert the view to string.

Comment: $body = $this->load->view('users/forgot_password_email',' ' ,true);

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines right after loading library with config .

```
$this->email->set_header('MIME-Version', '1.0; charset=utf-8'); //must add this line
$this->email->set_header('Content-type', 'text/html'); //must add this line
```